# How to create custom formatting command

Tags: macros, formatting

I'd like to create a formatting command to use like so:

```
\myawesomecommand{Some awesome text.}
```

This should be interpreted as, for instance,

```
\textbf{\color{red} Some awesome text.}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `\newcommand\myawesomecommand[1]{\textbf{\color{red} #1}}` helps? than you can use as `\myawesomecommand{Some awesome text.}`

Comment: @Zarko yes, thanks! I'll upvote it if you post it as an answer.

Comment: you already receive answer ... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\myawesomecommand}[1]{\textbf{\color{red} #1}}


\begin{document}

\myawesomecommand{Some awesome text.} 

\end{document}
```

[image]